# How I can order the list elements

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-select2

I'm creating a dropdown through the use of ui-select2=" "  how i can sort the list items in to the result

Html:

```
<input  style="width:100%"  type="text" ui-select2="selectuiOptions"     
 data-placeholder="Select or Add Process/Ingredient">
```

js:

```
    $scope.selectuiOptions = {
            data : $scope.processes,
}
```

how i can sort the list element into the result

Comment: ui-select2 with ng-option is incompatible.

Answer (score 0):

Here is example:

```
function MyCtrl($scope, orderByFilter)

var isReverse = true,
    propertyName = 'myProperty';

$scope.selectuiOptions = {
   data : orderByFilter($scope.processes, 'propertyName', isReverse),
   ...
}
```